# Updating an existing HTML link using GWT?

Tags: gwt

HTML file:

```
<a id="search">Search</a>
```

GWT Module:

```
Anchor searchLink = new Anchor("Search", Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setPath("search.html").buildString());
RootPanel.get("search").add(searchLink);
```

Results in:

```
<a id="search">Search
  <a class="gwt-Anchor" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/search.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997">Search</a>
</a>
```

Is there a way for me to edit the existing anchor (replacing its body) instead of inserting inside it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace element with my GWT widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075631/how-to-replace-element-with-my-gwt-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Document#getElementById()` to get the existing anchor Element instead of `RootPanel#get()`:

```
Anchor searchLink = Anchor.wrap(Document.get().getElementById("search"));
searchLink.setHref(Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().
  setPath("search.html").buildString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct use of GWT Document class is:

```
Document.get().getElementById("search")
```